# abstractmethod is not defined

Tags: python, abstract-class

I cannot run this code, because I get the exception:

```
NameError: name 'abstractmethod' is not defined
File "C:\Tests\trunk\PythonTests\AbstractClasses.py", line 12, in <module>
  class MyIterable:
File "C:\Tests\trunk\PythonTests\AbstractClasses.py", line 15, in MyIterable
  @abstractmethod

from abc import ABCMeta

class Foo(object):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print '__get_item__ Foo'
    def __len__(self):
        print '__len__ Foo'
    def get_iterator(self):
        print 'get_iterator Foo'
        return iter(self)

class MyIterable:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self):
        while False:
            yield None

    def get_iterator(self):
        return self.__iter__()

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is MyIterable:
            if any("__iter__" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
                print "I'm in __subclasshook__"
                return True
        return NotImplemented

MyIterable.register(Foo)

x=Foo()
x.__subclasshook__()
```

I'm sure that code is ok, because I got it from http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html

**EDIT**

Thanks for answer, it works now, but why

```
print '__subclasshook__'
```

this doesn't work ? I don't get in Debug I/0

Comment: Why `print 'I'm in __subclasshook__'` doesn't work?  Have you actually taken the time to count the quote characters `'`?

Comment: sorry, in real there is '__subclasshook__'. I wrote here another text to clarity :/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You only imported `ABCMeta`

```
from abc import ABCMeta
```

Also import `abstractmethod`

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
```

and everything should be fine.

Comment: So for others landing here, I want to point out that if you are only using `abstractmethod`, it seems you also need to import `ABCMeta` (sort of the opposite of the above issue)

Comment: `from abc import ABC, ABCMeta, abstractmethod` still not working!

Answer (score 6):

You need to import `abstractmethod` from `abc`. `abc` is the inbuilt Python package for [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html).

An example:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod

class Foo:
    def __init():
        pass
    
    @abstractmethod
    def bar():
        pass
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change import ABC to ABCMeta

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AbstractClassExample(ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        super().__init__()

    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        print("do_something")


class DoAdd42(AbstractClassExample):
    print("DoAdd42")

x = DoAdd42(4)
```

Comment: sorry, [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC) clearly shows that `ABCMeta` should be used as a `metaclass` and is not to be inherited from directly. For inheritance, one should use `ABC` class